# Adding event listener to a button which only has class id

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to add an even listener to sign in button of LinkedIn's first page which looks like this:

```
<button class="sign-in-form__submit-button" data-tracking-control-name="homepage-basic_signin-form_submit-button" data-tracking-litms="" type="submit">    Sign in        </button>
```

I am developing a password manager extension and I am planning to get user name and password when user clicks on sign in button however the below code does not work. Can you please help?

```
document.getElementsByClassName("sign-in-form__submit-button")[0].addEventListener("click", getinputs);

function getinputs(){
username = document.getElementById("session_key").value;
password = document.getElementById("session_password").value;
}
```

Comment: there is no `<form>` element ? so you can't use submit event ?

Comment: @Mister Jojo I did not check it but how can I use it? I mean I need to link my extension to this webpage and capture the fields just when user intracts with the page which I think my best option is using the button. Do you have any other idea? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Is your code an extension? chrome or FireFox or Edge ?

Comment: Chrome and this code is part of content.js

Comment: I don't see any problem in using a form in an extension, and it simplifies the code a lot. otherwise I don't understand why you have a submit button

Comment: My intention is that it listens for clicking on submit button and it captures the values typed into the username and password fields on LinkedIn. I was successful on sign up page of LinkedIn because I did exactly the same but fortunately on sign on page the register button has an ID and I used getElementbyId.addEventListener to capture them when the button is clicked. I am not successful with log in page because the button only has class name.

Comment: in fact you are trying to retrieve in your extension the data of a form entered on a web page when it is sent. Well (1) this is called hacking, (2) what you want to do is not feasible, because browsers are designed to prohibit this possibility

Comment: So how many password managers such as Firefox sync and lastpass do that? If it is hacking!

Comment: Search Chrome store there are hundreds of extensions which do this (LastPass and others) and are indeed extensions! any information could be used in malicious way! but as I mentioned it is because I want to develop such an extension

Comment: LastPass and other extensions do not capture login and password on customer interfaces, they must enter them themselves on LastPass first. The events managers respect all the logic of the sandbox

Comment: It does not change the fact that the events remain in their sandbox and cannot be recovered elsewhere, as in your "extension"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used another type of event listener for the input tag and it worked
Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that because you didn't write the code completely but it seems that you forget to write **var** before username and password

```
   function getinputs(){
      var username = document.getElementById("session_key").value;
      var password = document.getElementById("session_password").value;
      }
```

Comment: Nah, that's not the problem, I'm just stuck in this part of the code. So for the sake of simplicity I kept it short. When I console.log for username and password I see nothing. Not even errors in developer mode!

Answer (score 0):

I See Two Errors

1. The First Error I See You Declare The Function After Call it
2. The Seconde One You Call it in a Wrong Way instead Of `getinputs()`
   you Wrote `getinputs`

The Event Should Contain Your Function to Use It (Not Necessery If You Create Your Function Before You Call It As A Said Before)
So I'm Offering Two Solutions :

1- The First One With Function Inside Event

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("sign-in-form__submit-button")[0].addEventListener("click", getinputs , function getinputs(){
    username = document.getElementById("session_key").value;
    password = document.getElementById("session_password").value;
    });
```

2- The Seconde One Outside your Event :

```
function getinputs(){
username = document.getElementById("session_key").value;
password = document.getElementById("session_password").value;
}
document.getElementsByClassName("sign-in-form__submit-button")[0].addEventListener("click", getinputs());
```